# Verify if argv[1] is bigger than argv[2]

Tags: c, argv, strcmp

I'm trying to verify if argv[1] it's bigger than argv[2]. I noticed I can't directly do it since argv is a char. But no ideea about how I could transform it into a int. There you have my code. Thanks in advance!

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argv[1] > argv[2])
        printf("it's superior");
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: What are the possible arguments you're trying to check, are these numbers? Then you need to convert string to an integer. One possible choice is to use `atoi()`

Comment: don't use `atoi` if you want reliability

Comment: Yep, these are 2 numbers.

Comment: The `argv[x]` arguments are ALWAYS (as the param declaration indicates) C strings (memory buffer 0 terminated). You cannot compare C strings  as it were numbers. You have to use strcmp or convert the strings in numbers using one of the opportune conversion functions (atoi, strtol, strtod ... and so on).

Comment: Ok. Can you please give me an example about using atoi with argv? I've seen some but with only a value.